# Google colab is not working cant load java script files

Tags: google-colaboratory

```
Could not load the JavaScript files needed to display output.
This is probably because your Google Account login access has expired or because third-party cookies 
are not allowed by your browser.
```

this error appears every time i try to run my code  even though it was working for weeks but this but this happened without any reason .

i tried to enable the third_party cookies from settings and paste this ([*.]googleusercontent.com) in the allow section but the error Still showing up.

Answer (score 0):

I pasted `https://colab.research.google.com` and `[*.]google.com` in the allow section and it worked